# my android layout isn't aligning buttons with edittext correctly

Tags: android, android-layout, android-relativelayout

My buttons and edittext are not right and left aligned carefully .. can anyone explain to me how to solve it?
Also.. the prompt is not beginning from the top of the edittext ... why??

**EDIT:** I want the 2 buttons horizntally aligned and the edittext below them.

**EDIT:** I've uploaded a pic on this link:  http://t.co/qNA0gssOUG
sorry for inclarity.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="#efefef"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context=".ComposeActivity" >

<Button
    android:id="@+id/tweet_button"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/edittext_tweet"
    android:text="@string/tweet_button" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/cancel_button"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@id/edittext_tweet"
    android:text="@string/cancel_button" />

<EditText
    android:id="@id/edittext_tweet"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_below="@id/cancel_button"
    android:background="#ffffff"
    android:focusable="true"
    android:inputType="textMultiLine" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: need all in horizontal???

Comment: `android:layout_alignRight="@+id/edittext_tweet"` remove the +, with the plus you are creating a ID, you need to reference one that already exists, in this case edittext_tweet

Comment: @PiyushGupta no, I need the 2 buttons aligned horizontally and the edittext below them.

Answer (score 0):

I don't get what you are looking for but perhaps below code may help you. It will give you tweet button on left, cancel button on right and in between these two a Edit Text all Horizontally aligned.

```
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#efefef"
    tools:context=".ComposeActivity" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/tweet_button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:text="tweet" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/edittext_tweet"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/cancel_button"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/tweet_button"
        android:background="#ffffff"
        android:focusable="true"
        android:inputType="textMultiLine" />

    <Button
        android:id="@id/cancel_button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:text="Cancel" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

@user I copied your code and tried it. I don't know what's wrong with it.

[pic.twitter.com/HH4MU33EBk](http://pic.twitter.com/HH4MU33EBk)  --here's what your code created.

perhaps, post an illustration.

Comment: I really want to post a pic, but I don't have enough reputation to do that!

Comment: check out what I posted in twitter. pic.twitter.com/HH4MU33EBk you don't need an account to view it.

Answer (score 0):

since your using RelativeLayout , you can align controls (views) relative to one another or relative to the layout using

to align your view relative to it's parent container use:

```
android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
```

and then u can specify layout_marginLeft/Right/Top/Bottom value in "dp" to have ur component spaced from the border of the container

if u need to align other components relative to that view element 
use

```
android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/'the refrence component id'"
android:layout_toRightOf="@id/'the refrence component id'"
android:layout_above="@id/'the refrence component id'"
android:layout_below="@id/'the refrence component id'"
android:layout_alignBaseline="@id/'the refrence component id'"
```

here's a good link with visual examples

[A Visual Guide to Relative Layouts In Android](http://knowledge.lapasa.net/?p=334)

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest to use a LinearLayout (vertical), put another LinearLayout (horizontal) including the buttons in it and add the EditText...

{
{[Button][Button]}
[   EditText   ]
}